# How to display the current year in a Django template?

Tags: python, django

What is the inbuilt template tag to display the present year dynamically. Like "2011" what would be the template tag to display that?

Answer (score 396, accepted):

The full tag to print just the current year is [`{% now "Y" %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now). Note that the Y must be in quotes.

Comment: For the record, {% now %} won't give proper results for users within different time zone than the server.

Comment: @Thomas True for some cases, however, the most common use case I've seen for wanting the current year is a copyright notice, and it's really not that important for it to be perfect for that 24 hours while Jan 1st makes its way around the world.

Comment: incidentally, that code is wrong, the `Y` must be quoted as in cabishek's answer.

Comment: If I was getting month i.e. "M" how would I get "Nov" to "November"

Comment: @Josh the full docs are https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date, but you're looking for `F` instead of `M`

Answer (score 53):

`{% now 'Y' %}` is the correct syntax

Answer (score 16):

I have used the following in my Django based website

```
{% now 'Y' %}
```

You can visit & see it in the footer part where I have displayed the current year using the below code(CSS part is omitted so use your own).

```
<footer class="container-fluid" id="footer">
    <center>
        <p>
           &copy;
           {% now 'Y' %}, 
           PMT Boys hostel <br> 
           All rights reserved
        </p>
    </center>
</footer>
```

And it is displaying the following centred text in my website's footer.

```
©2018, PMT Boys hostel 
All rights reserved
```

Answer (score 15):

[`{% now %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now)

Comment: You may have forgotten this additional trivia: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date

Answer (score 0):

In my template, aside from the current year, I needed a credit card expiration year dropdown with 20 values (starting with the current year).  The `select` values needed to be 2 digits and the display strings 4 digits.  To avoid complex template code, I wrote this simple template tag:

```
@register.filter
def add_current_year(int_value, digits=4):
    if digits == 2:
        return '%02d' % (int_value + datetime.datetime.now().year - 2000)
    return '%d' % (int_value + datetime.datetime.now().year)
```

And used it in the following manner:

```
<select name="card_exp_year">
    {% for i in 'iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii' %}
    <option value="{{ forloop.counter0|add_current_year:2 }}">{{ forloop.counter0|add_current_year:4 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: @mohammedqudah, depends on your needs!